# How to decipher error code from Cuda-Memcheck

Tags: cuda

**Problem:**

Running cuda-memcheck on Windows in a console is reporting

> Program hit error 2 on CUDA API call to cudaLaunch.

The problem is what does "error 2" mean? I thought it was the error code contained in the cudaError enum but I am not sure.

**Platform:** Windows 7 (64-bit)

**Compiler** (Visual Studio 2010)

**Compute capability**: 1.1 (Quadro FX 3800M)

**CUDA version** (5.0)

**Question:** How do you find out what the error number means?

**Cuda-Memcheck results**

```
    Running 1 test case...
    ========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
    ========= Program hit error 2 on CUDA API call to cudaLaunch 
    =========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\system32\nvcuda.dll
                     (cuD3D11CtxCreate + 0x11f702) [0x144812]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\cudart64_50_35.dll
                     (cudaLaunch + 0x2a5) [0x235c5]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                 (__device_stub__ZN17signal_processing6kernel24cfar_move_valid_elementsEPjPK6float2PS2_fS1_S1_ + 0xab) [0x313cb]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (signal_processing::kernel::cfar_move_valid_elements + 0x1d) [0x313ed]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (signal_processing::algorithm::constant_false_alarm_rate::identify_valid + 0x1af) [0x2a46f]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (signal_processing::algorithm::constant_false_alarm_rate::process + 0x2e3) [0x2bc03]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (server::stream::operator() + 0x5c2) [0x20ce2]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function + 0x21) [0xe01a1]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
                     (endthreadex + 0x43) [0x21d9f]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
                     (endthreadex + 0xdf) [0x21e3b]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
                     (BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xd) [0x1652d]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
                     (RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21) [0x2c521]
    =========
    ========= Program hit error 17 on CUDA API call to cudaFree 
    =========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\system32\nvcuda.dll
                     (cuD3D11CtxCreate + 0x11f702) [0x144812]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\cudart64_50_35.dll
                     (cudaFree + 0x248) [0x24a98]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (signal_processing::algorithm::pulse_compression::~pulse_compression + 0x38) [0x29228]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_pd<signal_processing::algorithm::pulse_compression * __ptr64,boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<signal_processing::algorithm::pulse_compression> >::dispose + 0x18) [0x18538]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (server::stream::~stream + 0xe7) [0x167e7]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::detail::thread_data<server::stream>::`scalar deleting destructor' + 0x26) [0x14246]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::thread::join + 0x12d) [0xe146d]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::thread_group::join_all + 0x49) [0x13fd9]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (unit_tests::test_stream::test_method + 0x430) [0x14a50]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::unit_test::ut_detail::callback0_impl_t<boost::unit_test::ut_detail::unused,void (__cdecl*)(void)>::invoke + 0xc) [0x6dcc]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::unit_test::ut_detail::callback0_impl_t<int,boost::unit_test::`anonymous namespace'::zero_return_wrapper_t<boost::unit_test::callback0<boost::unit_test::ut_detail::unused> > >::invoke + 0x16) [0xdab16]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::execution_monitor::catch_signals + 0xb1) [0xdb561]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::execution_monitor::execute + 0x37) [0xdb627]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::unit_test::unit_test_monitor_t::execute_and_translate + 0x5e) [0xdaa8e]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::unit_test::framework_impl::visit + 0x122) [0x92cc2]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::unit_test::traverse_test_tree + 0xae) [0x8d82e]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::unit_test::traverse_test_tree + 0xae) [0x8d82e]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::unit_test::framework::run + 0x4a2) [0x93c62]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (boost::unit_test::unit_test_main + 0x7e) [0xe5ffe]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Users\Stephen.Torri\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\signal_processing\Win64\Bin\RelWithDebInfo\test_stream.exe
                     (__tmainCRTStartup + 0x11a) [0xe2082]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
                     (BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xd) [0x1652d]
    =========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21) [0x2c521]
    =========
    ========= LEAK SUMMARY: 0 bytes leaked in 0 allocations
    ========= ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors
```

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to [cudaLaunch()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__EXECUTION_1gf4f3215d06b6d90849a3d977f9440002) in CUDA runtime API.

You can fine the meaning of the err code in that doc. [link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1g3f51e3575c2178246db0a94a430e0038)

> cudaErrorMemoryAllocation = 2
>
> The API call failed because it was unable to allocate enough memory to perform the requested operation.

On the other hand, I would suggest you to show more output of cuda-memcheck, usually it will show more human readable info than just a code.

Comment: ok. So the number does in fact match the contents of cudaError enumeration. Here is the output of a test program that is part of a larger program. The purpose of this test program was to eliminate a large portion of the larger program in order to find the causes of the leaks:

Comment: @Stephen Yes, I think you are right. It seems you don't have enough device mem for your program.

Comment: Alas I cannot rip out the laptop's wimpy card and easily replace it with another. Thanks for looking at this. For now I will do what I can until I get back to work where the bigger machine has no such limitation. I think the second error is the result of trying to do cudaFree on a failed cudaMalloc pointer.